# (ASP.NET) Master Page has a BG image,Unable to load that BG image in content pages

Tags: asp.net, web-config, master-pages

`.Master` pages are organized as

**root/masters/xyz.master**

`.aspx` content pages are organized as

**root/folder1/sub_folder/xyzw.aspx**

As you can see the problem arises due to folder hierarchy

Is there any way i can see my BG-image set in one of .master on all my content pages?

Please explain with an example

Recommend me possible solution with better organisation(i.e certain levels in folder

I have no errors/warning related to basic master page config. even tried to set MasterPageFile in `web.config` but no luck

[new - info]

last time,I forgot to tell the location of Images folder and i was out of station so i was unable to reply

Here u go,

```
**Master Page:**

 - root -> Master Pages ->Default.master
 - root -> Images -> BG_purp_patt_2.jpg

     <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
     CodeFile="Default.master.cs" Inherits="Master_Pages_Default" %>

ContentPlaceHolder(head)

     <body style="background-image: url('../Images/BG_purp_patt_2.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;">

ContentPlaceHolder(a)

ContentPlaceHolder(b)

ContentPlaceHolder(c)

**Start Page:** 

(Note. This page displays BG image )

 - root -> Home ->Home.aspx

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master Pages/Default.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home_Home" %>

ContentPlaceHolder(head)

ContentPlaceHolder(a)

ContentPlaceHolder(b)

ContentPlaceHolder(c)

**Another Content Page:**

(Note. There is no display of BG image in this and rest of 20 or 30 pages inside subfolders organised in this pattern(root ->folder ->folder ->page.aspx))

 - root -> Jobs & Tenders -> 1_Faculty Position -> Default.aspx

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master Pages/Default.master" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Jobs___Tenders_1_Faculty_Position_Default" %>

...ContentPlaceHolder(head)

..ContentPlaceHolder(a)

..ContentPlaceHolder(b)

..ContentPlaceHolder(c)
```

I hope its clear.

I think this would be more than enough, Again Problem is BG not visible in content pages other than home( why? )

Before u post I have tried using "~"   "../"  concatenation but no luck

I think composing-feature of stackoverflow must be made more easier  :p

Comment: Can you post the code/css that shows the issue.  you may want to look at ResolveUrl and ~

Comment: As @IrishChieftain said your markup is going to say for sure, but it sounds like you might be using a relative rather than absolute path to your image. If you set the background image in a separate CSS file, the image path should be relative to that CSS file, which might work better for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irrelevant of where you specify your image, ASP should resolve the correct path (use a `~` and the `runat` attribute):

```
<img src="~/path/to/image.png" runat="server" />
```

If you specify a background-image in CSS, try following:

```
body { background-image: url(~/path/to/image.png); }
```

Whenever you include your CSS file, use the `runat` attribute in the `head` tag:

```
<head runat="server">
...
</head>
```

Comment: Not the way to set a background image; normally set in CSS.

Comment: nyi gave an example of setting it using CSS on the page. If you are trying to set the BG image from a CSS file that should be done using a relative path to where the CSS was stored (common regardless of if it's ASP.NET or any other language)